# Node js npm error code 1 while installing node inspector

Tags: node.js, npm, node-inspector

Hello I'm kind of new to node js. I using node version 7.0.0 of CURRENT category.I was trying to install the node inspector using command prompt but ending up getting npm err code 1. I have tried to clean the npm cache but not working.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're not alone. Check [this](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/940) and [this](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/944). Seems it's problem in `node-inspector`, and better to find some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your 'npm'

```
npm install -g npm
```

I had the same issue running the above command and reinstalling the package fixed my issue.